# Gradient of a square complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, vector-analysis

I have a question please. If we assume that we have a function $f : \Omega \subset \mathbf{R}^{N}: \longrightarrow \mathbf{C}$ smooth enough. Do we have the following:
$$ \nabla (f) \bar{f} = \frac{1}{2} \nabla \left| f \right|^{2}.$$

(If the function f is a real function this is always true. But for a complex function I'm not sure!!)

Comment: @MartinR, I think the lack of parentheses means it is the gradient of $f$ multiplied with the conjugate.

Comment: @ManateePink:  you are right, I just edit my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For complex-valued functions you have
$$ 
\nabla(|f|^2) = \nabla (\bar f f) = \bar f \nabla(f) + f \nabla(\bar f)\\
= \bar f \nabla(f) + \overline{\bar f \nabla(f)} = 2 \operatorname{Re}\left(\bar f \nabla(f)\right) \, ,
$$
i.e.
$$
 \frac 12 \nabla(|f|^2) = \operatorname{Re}\left(\bar f \nabla(f)\right) \, .
$$